# Python 3.5 + Arachni Web Scanner (REST) + ElasticSearch: Cannot add any index to ElasticSearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

**UPDATE**: Okay I got the script working for a few instances, but not all the time. Hmm, trying to find out why...

I'm trying to develop a Python wrapper for Arachni Web Scanner that also throws the reports it generates to ElasticSearch and it keeps throwing a 'mapper_parsing_exception' and ends up not adding any index to ElasticSearch

The scan itself and the report generation works, but it can't add anything to ElasticSearch.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json
import requests
import argparse
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import codecs

requestURL = 'http://localhost:7331'
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])

def new_scan(scan_url, scan_checks = None):
    if scan_checks is None:
            params = {"url":scan_url}
    else:
            params = {"url":scan_url, "checks":scan_checks}

    responseURL = requestURL + "/scans"
    response = requests.post(responseURL, data =    json.dumps(params),headers=headers)
    return response

def monitor_scan(scan_id):
    responseURL = requestURL + "/scans/" + scan_id
    response = requests.get(responseURL)
    return response

def retrieve_report(scan_id):
    responseURL = requestURL + "/scans/" + scan_id + "/report.json"
    response = requests.get(responseURL)
    return response

def pause_scan(scan_id):
    responseURL = requestURL + "/scans/" + scan_id + "/pause"
    response = requests.put(responseURL,headers=headers)
    return response

def resume_scan(scan_id):
    responseURL = requestURL + "/scans/" + scan_id + "/resume"
    response = requests.put(responseURL,headers=headers)
    return response

def shutdown_scan(scan_id):
    responseURL = requestURL + "/scans/" + scan_id
    response = requests.delete(responseURL,headers=headers)
    return response

def get_status(scan_id):
    scan_status = monitor_scan(scan_id)
    status_json = scan_status.json()
    return status_json['busy']

def add_report(scan_id):
    scan_report = arachni_python.retrieve_report(scan_id)
    es.index(index='scan_reports',doc_type='report',id=scan_id,body=scan_report.json(),request_timeout=30)
    report = es.get(index='scan_reports', doc_type='report', id=scan_id)
    print(json.dumps(report, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Arachni Web Scanner")
    parser.add_argument('-u',"--url",required=True, help="URL to scan")
    parser.add_argument('-c',"--checks", help="checks (type '*' to scan all")
    args = parser.parse_args()


    checks = ['*']


    url_scan = new_scan(args.url,checks)
    reader = codecs.getreader("utf-8")
    scan_json = url_scan.json()
    scan_id = scan_json['id']
    print(scan_id)


    scan_status = get_status(scan_id)


    while scan_status is True:
            print('.', end='',flush=True)
            scan_status = get_status(scan_id)

    add_report(scan_id)
    shutdown_scan(scan_id)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Stack Trace:

```
File "./arachni_python.py", line 87, in <module>
main()
File "./arachni_python.py", line 83, in main
add_report(scan_id)
File "./arachni_python.py", line 57, in add_report
es.index(index='scan_reports',doc_type='report',id=scan_id,body=scan_report.json(),timeout="30s")
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 71, in _wrapped
return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 300, in index
_make_path(index, doc_type, id), params=params, body=body)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 327, in perform_request
status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 124, in perform_request
self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py", line 122, in _raise_error
raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'failed to parse')
```

ES Logs from my last run:

```
2016-12-22T04:59:43,415][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] initialized
[2016-12-22T04:59:43,415][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [m4FdZIM] starting ...
[2016-12-22T04:59:43,683][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [m4FdZIM] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {[::1]:9300}, {127.0.0.1:9300}
[2016-12-22T04:59:46,767][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [m4FdZIM] new_master {m4FdZIM}{m4FdZIM3R02tIWRrAozWiw}{Mi4wPefORLq5DYlO9r_ClQ}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)
[2016-12-22T04:59:46,817][INFO ][o.e.h.HttpServer         ] [m4FdZIM] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {[::1]:9200}, {127.0.0.1:9200}
[2016-12-22T04:59:46,818][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [m4FdZIM] started
[2016-12-22T04:59:46,879][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [m4FdZIM] recovered [1] indices into cluster_state
[2016-12-22T04:59:47,085][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [m4FdZIM] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[scan_reports][1]] ...]).
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace you get?

Comment: Added it to the main post @Val

Comment: Actually, I meant the `mapper_parsing_exception` stack trace from the ES logs.

Comment: where is it usually located? can't seem to find any on the logs :\

Comment: Usually in `/var/log/elasticsearch`

Comment: already added the latest entries to the main post

Comment: You need to find an occurence of `mapper_parsing_exception` in your ES logs, the above one is not helpful.

Comment: Can't seem to find any entries related to that.